# ALV is not refreshed after edit. Why?

Tags: abap, alv, dynpro

I know my problem has been asked hundred times.
But I still cannot find any suitable solution for me

1. I have a dropdown, every time I change data in dropdown it will load new data based on dropdown data
2. From step one, I refresh editable ALV
3. Any change in editable ALV willbe saved (another action for saving)

My problem if, After I save, I can't refresh my ALV.

But it's not problem if I haven't pressed save button

**NOTE :**
in [SAP forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11569394/problem-with-oo-alv-refresh.html), they told me to move refresh function to PBO, I tried this but still failed.

Attached Code is Step 1 is "when SET_P" in this code

**PBO**

```
    MODULE pbo_1000 OUTPUT.
       IF flag = 0.
         SET PF-STATUS '1000'.
         SET TITLEBAR  '1000'.
         PERFORM create_toolbar.
         PERFORM create_catalog.
         PERFORM select_data.
     
         CREATE OBJECT ob_custom
           EXPORTING
             container_name = 'CCTRL'.
         CREATE OBJECT ob_grid
           EXPORTING
             i_parent      = ob_custom
             i_appl_events = 'X'.
     
         PERFORM create_dropbox.
         CALL METHOD ob_grid->set_table_for_first_display
           EXPORTING
             i_structure_name     = 'TYPE'
             it_toolbar_excluding = lt_toolbar
             is_layout            = lyt
           CHANGING
             it_fieldcatalog      = fld[]
             it_outtab            = itab[].
     
         CALL METHOD ob_grid->set_ready_for_input
           EXPORTING
             i_ready_for_input = 1.
         CALL METHOD ob_grid->register_edit_event
           EXPORTING
             i_event_id = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_evt_enter.
       ENDIF.
    ENDMODULE.
```

**PAI**

```
    MODULE user_command_1000 INPUT .
       DATA: v_perio(6) TYPE c.

       CASE sy-ucomm.
         WHEN 'BACK' OR 'EXIT' OR 'CANCEL'.
           LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
         WHEN 'SAVE'.
           PERFORM save_data.
           PERFORM send_email.
     
         WHEN 'SET_S'.
           flag = 1.
           PERFORM set_status.
           CALL METHOD ob_grid->refresh_table_display
             EXPORTING
               is_stable = stbl.
    
         WHEN 'SET_P'.
           flag = 1.
           PERFORM select_data.
           CALL METHOD ob_grid->refresh_table_display
             EXPORTING
               is_stable      = stbl.
       ENDCASE.
    ENDMODULE.
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will need the **CHECK_CHANGED_DATA** method called as first thing in the PAI, which would fire up the events **DATA_CHANGED** and **DATA_CHANGED_FINISHED**.

But most important thing is, that it will synchronize the OLE object with the instance backend and then when you are calling the **REFRESH_TABLE_DISPLAY** it would refresh your ALV properly. I don't have any example at the moment, but I can maybe try next week when I have access to system.

By the way in PBO you don't need to have the variable **flag** you can use check if the ALV object has been already initialized or not and according to this you can create/refresh alv. Something like this:

```
if alvGridRef is NOT bound .
  data(container) = new cl_gui_custom_container( ) .
  data(alvGridRef) = new cl_gui_alv_grid( ) .
else .
  alvGridRef->refresh_table_display( ) .
endif .
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in an application that needed to be refreshed when saved because some calculations had to change in the screen. I set part of the following code in the command form for the 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY' function module.

```
form user_command using r_ucomm     like sy-ucomm
                        rs_selfield type slis_selfield.
  data: ref_grid type ref to cl_gui_alv_grid, l_valid type c.

  if ref_grid is initial.
    call function 'GET_GLOBALS_FROM_SLVC_FULLSCR'
      importing
        e_grid = ref_grid.
  endif.

  if not ref_grid is initial.
    call method ref_grid->check_changed_data
      importing
        e_valid = l_valid.
  endif.
  rs_selfield-refresh = 'X'.

  ...

  if not ref_grid is initial.
    call method ref_grid->refresh_table_display( ) .
  endif.

endform.
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve this by **manually triggering PBO**. You stated that the Editing is saved, so you can just display the ALV in PBO again:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SAPGUI_SET_FUNCTIONCODE'
           EXPORTING
             functioncode           = 'REFRESH'
           EXCEPTIONS
             function_not_supported = 1 
             OTHERS                 = 2.
```

After this action, `sy-ucomm` in PBO has the value `REFRESH`.